# Differences between the many versions of neuromorphic hardware

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, neural-network

There is a ton of neuromorhpic hardware being pumped out these days. Off the top of my head, I can name [IBM](http://www.research.ibm.com/cognitive-computing/neurosynaptic-chips.shtml#fbid=WCIDcTXRNC3) (BlueGene and TrueNorth), [Qualcomm](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/520211/qualcomm-to-build-neuro-inspired-chips/), [Neurogrid](http://web.stanford.edu/group/brainsinsilicon/neurogrid.html), Brainstorm (Neurogrid 2.0), [Spinnaker](http://www.artificialbrains.com/spinnaker), (questionably) [Peter van der Made's chip](http://higherintelligencebook.com/), [BrainScaleS](http://www.artificialbrains.com/brainscales), in addition to various FPGA and VLSI implementations that I've come across.

However, has there been an extensive comparison of these various hardware approaches and their usefulness/extensibility?

For an example of the comparison I'm looking for, Spinnaker can run Nengo (a brain simulation software based on the NEF), while Peter's chip doesn't run software, thus I would claim that Spinnaker is more useful than Peter's. I would assume (naively) that IBMs TrueNorth chip would be somewhere in the middle, since it is programmable, but does not support learning.

Comment: This seems impossible to answer as written. It might be possible to answer if you narrowed down the set of hardwares to compare to 2-3, or more precisely specified the parameters you want all these compared on.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr I agree. I voted to close it (instead of deleting it) until I get time to re-think how best to phrase this question.

Comment: This kind of hardware design does not work well...you can't mimic down to the macro level like proteins so its too early for anything but very complex neural nets...it would do that very well...neural nets only can estimate certain problems